# Ajax with angular and node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I'm trying to make an ajax request to my node.js application with Angularjs but i can't get data on the server side, i mean i can't get the value of the 'test' parameter.
here is my code

```
app.post('/ajaxget',(reg,res)=>
{
console.log(reg.body.test);
res.send("ajaxtest");
})
```

and here is my angularjs code

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <h1 style="color:red;"> {{x}} </h1>
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   var test = 'hello';
   $http.post('/ajaxget',test).then(function(response) {
     $scope.x = response.data;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```js
 $http.post('/ajaxget',test).then(function(response) {
```

to

```js
 $http.post('/ajaxget',{test}).then(function(response) {
```

Does that fix the problem?

Comment: I got 'Undefined' response.

Comment: Well... solve 1 problem at a time... does your server log test correctly?

Comment: Yeah, it does but i think i have a problem with the syntax of angular or node.js probably

Comment: try to change `res.send("ajaxtest");` to `res.send({test: "ajaxtest"});` and log what you get at your ui side

Comment: Thank you so much, i made a silly mistake and didn't use bodyparser.json in my project, that's why i coudln't get the parameter from the Ajax.